# Create user on ejabbred when user sign up in django app

Tags: python, django, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I am using django with jsxc (https://jsxc.org) to make user chat. I want to add user to ejabbed when user sign up on django. Right now in demo i have to manually create user on ejabberd and hard code in jsxc code. I want to make a django site with one to one user chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use API to create user in ejabberd. The command name is "register": https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/api/#register---register-a-user